# How does Jenkins determine that a stage in a pipeline has finished, so that it can continue?

Tags: jenkins, devops

If I got a Jenkins-file like this one:

```
...
stage("Clone Repo") {
        steps {
            sh "git clone https://github.com/jenkins-docs/simple-java-maven-app.git"
        }
    }
    stage("Build") {
        steps {
            dir("simple-java-maven-app") {
                sh ("mvn clean install")
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Test") {
        steps {
            dir("simple-java-maven-app") {
                sh ("mvn test")
            }
        }
    }
...
```

How is in the shown example blocking behaviour accomplished? Respectively: **How does Jenkins determine that the git clone-command has finished, so that the next stage can start?**

Comment: In this situation it would be when the `sh` step method completes, which would be when the method returns an exit code.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks a lot. If you like: Turn your comment into an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipeline stage completes when the final method completes. In this situation for the `Clone Repo`, then that would be when the `sh` step method completes. A method completes when it returns an exit code to Jenkins Pipeline. In this situation, it would be when the `sh` step method returns an exit code to Jenkins Pipeline, which would correspond to when `git` returns an exit code to the shell interpreter (up the stack).